# Module.exports = {} not recognized by IntelliSense

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

The CommonJS construct `module.exports = {}` does not provide import suggestions in JS files via VSCode IntelliSense.

IntelliSense provides a *TS error* handle on the `module.exports = {}` construct:

> File is a CommonJS module; it may be converted to an ES6 module.ts(80001)

Pressing the **Quick Fix** option converts the exports to ES6 format. After this, IntelliSense import suggestions work.

What also works is formatting the export as follows:

```js
module.exports.showText = showtext;
```

My files are:

**lib.js**

```js
function showText() {
  console.log('Text');
}

module.exports = {
  showText: showText,
}
```

**myCode.js**

```js
showText();  // <- no import suggestion provided
```

I would like to get the IntelliSense import suggestion without change of the `module.exports = {}` construct (I do not have the authorization to do this for the entire project code base).

I am not using a jsconfig.json file.

Comment: Once you provide a require statement, function signature is inferred which leads me to believe this is an inherent limitation with `require`, all other import syntaxes should work.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I do not see how this answer is related to my question. Why is the `module.exports = {}` construct not recognized by IntelliSense?

Comment: It is recognised once after you use `require`. It is just not recognised for automatic imports. As to why it is not, you should ask the developers of vscode on their repository. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues